# Рассчитать разницу в днях, не учитывая год?

Tags: java, дата, datetime

Есть две даты : 27.08.1995(день рождения) и 17.08.2018(сегодняшняя дата)

Как правильно рассчитать, что до ДР осталось 10 дней?

Были попытки сделать разными способами. Один из них такой:

```
Days.daysBetween(bDate, currentDate).getDays()
```

Но он выводит абсолютное количество дней - 8391

Comment: Выставите у второй даты год как у первой и сравните

Comment: А как вы без года будете учитывать високосный день, который попадет в диапазон?

Comment: @Maxim вы, простите, о чем?

Comment: @Kromster, очевидно о заголовке вопроса

Comment: Посчитайте разницу в целых годах. Добавьте их к дню рождения. И теперь уже считайте разницу в днях. Т.е. что-то вроде (пардон, в синтаксисах не силён) `Days.daysBetween(bDate.add(Days.yearsBetween(bDate, currentDate).getYears(),year), currentDate).getDays()`

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать ChronoUnit из Java 8:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class DifferenceBetweenTwoDate {

 static  int timeBetweenTwoDays(LocalDate birthday){
     LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); //Получаем сегодняшний день

     LocalDate nextBDay = birthday.withYear(today.getYear());

     //Проверка, был ли день рождения в этом году
     if (nextBDay.isBefore(today) || nextBDay.isEqual(today)) { 
         nextBDay = nextBDay.plusYears(1);
     }

     long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, nextBDay);
     System.out.println("There are " + daysBetween + " days until your next birthday");
     return (int)daysBetween;
 }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        timeBetweenTwoDays(LocalDate.of(1995, Month.AUGUST, 27)); //Передаём дату дня рождения
    }
}
```

Вывод:
`There are 10 days until your next birthday`

Comment: Аргументируйте минус?

Comment: @Kromster ChronoUnit это из java8

Comment: Кто минусовал? Дайте знать - почему. А то я алгоритм вырезал из работающей 100 лет программы и не буду знать, что там баг!

Comment: Полностью согласен, я про хроно не знал. Автору вопроса может быть чуть-чуть не понятен ваш код, я чуть-чуть подправлю с вашего позволения. Кто поставил -1 тот не прав.

Comment: А зачем у ``daysBetween`` тип ``long``?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Переводите уже и вывод ))

Comment: @Эникейщик, потому что `between()` возвращает `long`